# Render react component without repeating code

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a component that needs to load a certain item according to a props it receives from the parent component.

```
const Contract = ({ savingsFactors, isContract }) => (
    {isContract ? (
        <PutField
        label={label}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onBlur={...}
        items={savingsFactors === 'true' ? FORM_VALUES : FORM_VALUES_NORMAL}
        />        
    ) : (
        <PutField
        label={label}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onBlur={...}
        items={savingsFactors === 'true' ? ANOTHER_FORM_VALUES : ANOTHER_FORM_VALUES_NORMAL}
        />
    )}
);
```

**The only thing that changes is the values ​​inside the items.**

These values ​​are objects with arrays:

```
const FORM_VALUES = [
    { name: 'some name', value 'some value' },
    { name: 'some name', value 'some value' },
]
const FORM_VALUES_NORMAL = [
    { name: 'some name', value 'some value' },
    { name: 'some name', value 'some value' },
]
const ANOTHER_FORM_VALUES = [
    { name: 'some name', value 'some value' },
    { name: 'some name', value 'some value' },  
]
const ANOTHER_FORM_VALUES_NORMAL = [
    { name: 'some name', value 'some value' }
]
```

**Is there any way I don't need to repeat these two blocks of code?**

Comment: why not put the condition inside your `items` prop?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't accept if or ternary chaining

Comment: can you show us what you tried? it can definitely work that way

Comment: you can also define a variable `items` above the component, figure out what it needs to be then pass it `items={items}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always like to be as explicit as I can:

```
const Contract = ({ savingsFactors, isContract }) => {
  const isSavingsFactors = savingsFactors === 'true';
  const formValues = isSavingsFactors ? FORM_VALUES : FORM_VALUES_NORMAL;
  const anotherFormValues = isSavingsFactors ? ANOTHER_FORM_VALUES : ANOTHER_FORM_VALUES_NORMAL;
  const items = isContract ? formValues : anotherFormValues;

  return <PutField
     label={label}
     placeholder={placeholder}
     onBlur={...}
     items={items}
  />
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
        let itemsToUse = savingsFactors === 'true' ? FORM_VALUES : FORM_VALUES_NORMAL;
        if (!isContract) {
            itemsToUse = savingsFactors === 'true' ? ANOTHER_FORM_VALUES : ANOTHER_FORM_VALUES_NORMAL
        }
        return <PutField
            label={label}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            onBlur={...}
            items={itemsToUse}
        />
   
    }
```

Comment: I need to do this verification inside of const Contract?